# Ubuntu server /etc ownership

Tags: permissions, root

I have accidentally changed the owner:group for /etc on my dev server. I would like to reset it back to root:root. Can anyone help me with the required steps.
 If I try : chown root:root etc
 It refuses by saying ooperation not permitted

Comment: Did you keep track of the former ownership?

Comment: well, you mean the root

Comment: Thanks I solved my problem with a rescue boot using the installation USB drive

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo chown root:root /etc
```

I would not use recursive flag. Not everything in /etc is root:root

Did you change every ownership inside /etc?

Comment: yes, I did, it all happened because I was playing around with vsftpd.conf

Comment: Is there a way to reset the root password using the recovery mode

Comment: @NesanMano https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/84090/how-can-i-revert-a-chmod-on-the-etc-directory

Comment: Thanks I solved my problem with a rescue boot using the installation USB drive